# Command Line Control over a network

Tags: c#, c++, windows, linux, remote-access

Is there any way to remote into another PC and use it's command line with full access?

I'm trying to develop a server that will have complete control over all of its clients via the command line.

It will be a ubuntu server but all the clients will be Windows 7 Pro x64.

I would love to be able to write this script in VC# .Net 3.5 but I will do it in c++ as a last resort.

What are my options?

Comment: Sounds like SSH to me... though I don't know if you can SSH into a windows machine and get full control.

Comment: It's possible but there's also netcat: http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows

Comment: There are ssh servers for windows, though they tend to be either free or functional (pick one).

Comment: So you want to get a windows commandline from linux?

Comment: I'm trying to write a script that would allow me to run commands on the client's command line.

Comment: *FROM* linux though? Any reason you're stuck with that requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but you could always implement a C# client on the Windows machine that uses IPC to send input and read output from a command prompt, and you'd have a C++/mono C#/netcat server running on Linux. The client converts everything coming from the stream to a string and writes it to the command prompt, then gets the output and writes it to the stream.
Courtesy of Code Project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20250/Reverse-Connection-Shell

```
cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.OutputDataReceived += new
        DataReceivedEventHandler(CmdOutputDataHandler);
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();

public void CmdOutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess,
    DataReceivedEventArgs cmdout)
    {                         
                output.Append(cmdout.Data);
                writer.WriteLine(output);
                writer.Flush();                

    }

// Run this in a separate thread to prevent blocking
while (true)
{
input.Append(reader.ReadLine());
input.Append("\n");
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
input.Remove(0, input.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remote commandline?

I use [PSEXEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals) simply like this:

`psexec \\machinename cmd.exe`

Couldn't be any easier

**Sorry - I apparently missed the bit about needing to control it from linux.**

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this from within Linux, but it works a charm in a full Windows environment.  Look into PowerShell Remoting on your remote machines.  You might be able to connect to the remote machine through C# MONO on the Linux box, but I'm not sure if the proper classes are yet available in MONO.